# Mediawiki PAGENAME how to set the parameter to a specific page

Tags: mediawiki

I have PAGENAME

For example PAGE: iPad

I need two parameters for this page:

- Parameter PRICE: $999
- Parameter AVAILABLE: Available, Not available

How can I get there parameters on page?
I would like to be able to get, in addition than {{PAGENAME}}, parameters on the page ?

And where could I store a lot of these parameters?

For example:

```
iPad1 — $999 — Available
iPad2 — $1999 — Available
iPad3 — $2999 — Not available
iPad4 — $3999 — Available
iPad5 — $2999 — Not available
etc.
```

How is it edit more comfortable for a lot of parameters?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you want to achieve? You want to store somewhere parameters values, then have one parameter on the GET query and fetch the parameters matching this value?

Answer (score 1):

I work on the Pixel Dungeon Wiki a lot and it has a [Data template](http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Template%3aData) which can be used to store information about an item.

To use it, copy the template over then create a page called ipad/data.

Then add to ipad/data:

```
{{Data|{{{1|}}}|{{{2|}}}|{{{3|}}}|{{{4|}}}|{{{$|}}}
 | iPad1price     = $999
 | iPad1available = AVAILABLE
 | iPad2price     = $1999
 | iPad2available = AVAILABLE
 ...
}}
```

Then you can access the information on the page with:

```
iPad1 price is {{:ipad/data||iPad1price}}
```

The [Data template](http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Template%3aData/doc) documentation is quite good for more info on this